# When does caching name-server include the authority section?

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to find out the authoritative name-servers for *swedbank.se* domain. I queried few caching name-servers for *swedbank.se* and while some answered the authoritative name servers, then others did not. For example Google public DNS servers:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 swedbank.se +noall +authority

; <<>> DiG 9.6.1-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 swedbank.se +noall +authority
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
$ dig @isp-nameserver swedbank.se +noall +authority

; <<>> DiG 9.6.1-P1 <<>> @isp-nameserver swedbank.se +noall +authority
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
swedbank.se.            2719    IN      NS      ns2.foreningssparbanken.se.
swedbank.se.            2719    IN      NS      ns1.foreningssparbanken.se.
swedbank.se.            2719    IN      NS      ns3.foreningssparbanken.se.
$
```

Is this just a matter of caching name-server configuration? Or is there some other reason for such behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure about the difference in behaviour between the two servers but if you're trying to get list of name-servers for the domain why not just ask for the NS records? dig ns swedbank.se

Comment: Since you're still active on other SE sites, could we trouble you to accept the answer? It keeps these questions from showing up on the unanswered reports.

Answer (score 1):

The most precise answer is "when required to by RFC, and a few other cases besides".

The only times you are guaranteed to see an AUTHORITY section is when the remote server is replying with zero records in the ANSWER section (and even then, only when the rcode is NOERROR or NXDOMAIN). The most common cases I know of are:

- Querying an authoritative server for a record that has been delegated to another server
- Receiving a NXDOMAIN response
- Querying a recursive server without the `RD` (recursion desired) flag set when the record is not in cache. Using dig, this would be accomplished via the `+norecurse` option.

Outside of the circumstances required by RFC, what you will get in that field is implementation specific and unreliable. Some nameserver software provide options for not serving up this data except when required to by RFC, which is useful to reduce the per-reply packet size in amplification attack scenarios. An example of this is BIND9's `minimal-responses` option.

> **minimal-responses**
>    If yes, then when generating responses the server will only add records to the authority and additional data sections when they are required (e.g. delegations, negative responses). This may improve the performance of the server. The default is no.

In short, unless a referral or NXDOMAIN is involved you should consider the data in the AUTHORITY section as a convenience factor only. When writing code that analyzes DNS replies, I only look at the AUTHORITY section if the rcode was NOERROR with zero records in the ANSWER section.