# dns lookup at different dns servers

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

when I perform a dig lookup to look for dns record for a domain name, server A gives a non empty dns record, but server B gives nothing. why? is there a more consistent approach?

server A

```
# dig cubagob.cu

; > DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 > cubagob.cu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:

;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cubagob.cu.            IN  A

;; Query time: 266 msec
;; SERVER: 69.64.66.11#53(69.64.66.11)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 16 17:18:11 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 28
```

server B

```
dig cubagob.cu

; > DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 > cubagob.cu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:

;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cubagob.cu.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cu.         2037    IN  SOA ns.ceniai.net.cu. cu-tech.ceniai.inf.cu. 2015021600 3600 1800 604800 3600

;; Query time: 161 msec
;; SERVER: 4.2.2.1#53(4.2.2.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 16 17:18:29 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 97
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you omitted the line containing `->>HEADER<<-`? Status codes are usually very pertinent when it comes to asking DNS questions.

Answer (score 1):

Those are both empty responses with zero answers. (literally, both say `ANSWER: 0`) The only difference is [whether those servers are providing you the AUTHORITY section as a courtesy](https://serverfault.com/q/659125/152073).

If you want a consistent output, you should either use `+short` (for answers only) or disable all output settings with `+noall` and selectively enable what you want to see. That said, shell scripting against the output returned by `dig` leaves much to be desired. If you need to precisely extract data from reply packets, it's recommended that you use your favorite scripting/programming language and a library suited to the task.